# OData API with dot in Controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

Right now I have an API that has some OData controllers.
/api/Customers
/api/Addresses

The Customers controller returns 1 or more customers holding an address collection.
The Addresses controller returns Addresses

It is required from me to change the Addresses controller to have the following endpoint /api/Customers.Addresses

I find a lot of examples how to handle dots in parameters but not in the controller name itself.

What should be changed to handle this requirement?

Comment: This isn't possible unless you used some kind of re-write rule on the webserver itself. Controllers cannot have special characters in their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is odata v4 you could use the `ODataRoutePrefixAttribute`. Decorate the controller with

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Customers.Addresses")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is Odata v3. But maybe a good reason to upgrade